# Can I using main(string[] args ) function from 1 project to another project?

Tags: c#, function, class, reference, helper

### I have TimeManagement project and Takenote project to. How can I use main function from TimeManagement to use in Takenote?

I've tried this, but It not works.

```
using TimeManagement; //I have add References
TimeManagement.program c = new TimeManagement.program;
            c.Main(string[] args );
```

Thank all ^^

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: I using C# ^^ I'm newbie

Comment: When you say it does not work, could you post the error too? Might be helpful.

Comment: Main is usually a static method, so you would have to call it as one.... as in TimeManagement.Project.Main()

Comment: See marked duplicate for the ideal approach. I.e. you can reference your `TimeManagement` project and just call its `Main()` method directly. It's a `static` method, so you have to call `TimeManagement.Main()`, not try to create a `TimeManagement` object. A less-than-ideal approach would be to reuse the `Program.cs` file itself in your project, making sure each project has the same types for that file to call to run the actual program.

Comment: @Milney I have tried it. but I have error

Comment: " there is no argument that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'args' of 'program.Main(string[])"   <br> --------- I tried to add some values in main but it not works